# Ticking noise coming from the suspension

Tags: dodge, charger, clicking

I hit a speed bump in my 2016 Dodge charger and now everytime I go 20 mph on a right turn I hear a fast clanking noise. It only happens when making a right turn and it only happens around 20 mph

I jacked up all the wheels and stepped on the gas while turning and I couldn't reproduce the noise, there's no play in the steering wheel and all of the wheel bearings are solid-no play at 12 and 6 or 3 and 9. I tried used a pry bar on swing arm and the struts and didn't hear anything clanking noise.

I immediately thought rear drivers side CV shaft when I was turning to the right at 20 mph and heard a repeated clank but the boots are good and there's no play in the rear CV's.

When I push at 3 and 9 on the front tires, the steering wheel moves with it, there's no locking position, never seen that happen before.

Comment: You've re-torqued all the lug nuts? Best to check this soon before you drive much more.

Comment: @MTA, I didn't think of that. I guess I just figured 12-6 and 3-9 would of had play if the nuts were loose

Comment: Rechecked the torque at 115 ft lbs on all 4 and everything was tight.

Comment: You've confirmed that no part of the exhaust system has slipped off a hangar? When you turn right the exhaust could sway left and rub on a rotating part of the drivetrain.